# Animate SVG on hover - Make a smile from dots on hover

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-animate

I have an SVG file with dots in in straight line. What I want to achieve is when a user hover on the svg file the dots to become a smile like the attached image.

The transition need to be smooth.

What is the best approach here? Can I do it with only css or I should use js also?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a [SMIL animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html), this is possible without any scripting. It morphs the cubic bezier path from straight to curved and back. The animation is triggered by `mouseover` and `mouseout` events over a transparent rectangle that sits on top of the line.

The line itself uses the combination of two little tricks: You can set a `pathLength` as an attribute, so that `stroke-dasharray` then computes dash lengths according to it. And for a `stroke-dasharray: 0 1` in combination with `stroke-linecap`, the zero-length dashes are displayed as dots with the stroke width as their diameter. Just play with the values for `pathLength` and `stroke-width` to change the distance of the dots and their size.

```css
#line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
#overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="150">
  <path id="line" d="M 10 50 C 35 50 65 50 90 50" pathLength="15">
    <animate attributeName="d" begin="overlay.mouseover" dur="0.3s"
             fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"
             from="M 10 50 C 35 50 70 50 90 50"
             to="M 15 30 C 20 70 80 70 85 30"/>
    <animate attributeName="d" begin="overlay.mouseout" dur="0.3s"
             fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"
             from="M 15 30 C 20 70 80 70 85 30"
             to="M 10 50 C 35 50 65 50 90 50"/>
  </path>
  <rect id="overlay" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the next example I'm calculating the position of the dots on the paths each at one tenth of the path's total length calculated with getTotalLength. For each circle I'm setting the value of the initial cx (in this case since the initial cy==0 I don't set it.

Also inside each circle I'm adding 2 `<animate>` elements that will animate the cx and the cy to the next position on the curbed path.

The animation will begin on click.

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";//svg namespace
const dur = .5;// the animation duration
let circles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("circle"))

let la = a.getTotalLength();
let lb = b.getTotalLength();
let start = {x:-100,y:0}

circles.forEach((c,i) =>{
  let da = i*la/10;
  let db = i*lb/10;
  let pa = a.getPointAtLength(da); 
  let pb = b.getPointAtLength(db); 
  c.setAttribute("cx",pa.x);
  
  let a1 = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS,"animate");
  a1.setAttribute("attributeName","cx");
  a1.setAttribute("from",pa.x);
  a1.setAttribute("to",pb.x);
  a1.setAttribute("dur",dur);
  a1.setAttribute("begin","svg.click");  
  c.appendChild(a1);
  
  
  let a2 = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS,"animate");
  a2.setAttribute("attributeName","cy");
  a2.setAttribute("from",pa.y);
  a2.setAttribute("to",pb.y);
  a2.setAttribute("dur",dur);
  a2.setAttribute("begin","svg.click");  
  c.appendChild(a2);
})

svg.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  circles.forEach((c,i) =>{
  let db = i*lb/10
  let pb = b.getPointAtLength(db);  
  c.setAttribute("cx",pb.x)
  c.setAttribute("cy",pb.y)
})
})
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
path{fill:none; stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="-150 -50 300 150" width="300">
  <path id="a" d="M-100,0 A15000,15000 0 0 0 100,0"/>
  <path id="b" d="M-100,0 A150,150 0 0 0 100,0"/>
  
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle r="5" />
</svg>
```

In the example the paths used to calculate the position of the circles are stroked. You can remove the stroke from the CSS.